# Ruby loop question and dumping results into YAML file

Tags: ruby, yaml

I am working on a Ruby script that will dump a key, value pair into a yaml file. But for some reason my loop is only grabbing the last instance in the loop. There should be multiple key value pairs.

Code:

```
# Model for languages Table
class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
end

# Model for elements Table
class Element < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :element_translations
end

# Model for element_translations Table
class ElementTranslation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :element
end

# Find ALL languages
lang = Language.all
# Get all elements
elements = Element.where("human_readable IS NOT NULL")
info = ''

elements.each do |el|
  lang.each do |l|
    et = el.element_translations.where("language_id = ?", l.id)
    et.each do |tran|
      info = {
        el.human_readable.to_s => tran.content.to_s
      }
    end
    File.open(l.code.to_s + ".yml", "w", :encoding => "UTF-8") do |f|
      YAML.dump(info, f)
    end
  end
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
info = {
  el.human_readable.to_s => tran.content.to_s
}
```

did you mean:

```
info << {
  el.human_readable.to_s => tran.content.to_s
}
```

Otherwise you're just re-assigning `info` each time.

If you're going to do this, make info an array: `info = []` as opposed to `info = ''`.

Comment: Thanks man! This worked like a charm! I have a new issue though. I have UTF-8 characters in my DB but when I dump the data to my YAML file I am getting `?` where the UTF-8 characters should be... any ideas on this?

Comment: @dennis - probably worth asking in a separate question.

Comment: I actually was able to figure out my problem... Here is my newest issue... for some reason each time the loop happens the array is not being reset. So the values being dumped into each YAML file are the not only the new array values but also the previous ones...

Answer (score 1):

In this loop

```
et.each do |tran|
  info = {
    el.human_readable.to_s => tran.content.to_s
  }
end
```

you repeatedly create new hash with one key `el.human_readable.to_s` with different values. However, even if you'll redo it as

```
info = {}
et.each do |tran|
  info[el.human_readable.to_s] = tran.content.to_s
end
```

you won't get more than 1 result, because key isn't changing - you'll just repeatedly assign it different values. What exactly do you want to get dumped? May be you'd want an array here, not key-value map?

```
info_array = []
et.each do |tran|
  info_array << tran.content.to_s
end
info = { el.human_readable.to_s => info_array }
```